# OS/X iChat: what client can videochat to this from Windows?

Tags: skype, ichat

Hi I have a mac and use iChat a lot with my overseas family.

However some of them have Windows PCs. I really don't like Skype. Is there any videoconferencing software that can talk directly to iChat from Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [iChat and AIM](http://www.mvldesign.com/video_conference_tutorial.html)?

Comment: Looks like that will work - I am going to have to see if the video side will be happy.